# Парсинг html с помощью lxml python

Tags: html, python, парсер

Есть такая часть html-документа:

```
<td class="name-td alLeft bordR">13.10.2016, Thu<span class="sp">|</span>17:00</td>
```

Мне нужно выдернуть дату (13.10.2016) и время (17:00).

Пробую:

```
t = lxml.html.parse(url)
nextMatchDate = t.findall(".//td[@class='ck']")[count].text
```

Но получаю ошибку

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Я думаю что это из-за того, что внутри `a` есть ещё вложенный тег. 
Как мне получить что-то на подобии

```
nextMatchDate = '13.10.2016 в 17:00'
```

Comment: Объясните, откуда берётся count и зачем оно тут вам

Comment: @andreymal я перебираю циклом. есть куча этих td с одинаковым классом, но разными значениями. count в данном случае это счётчик цикла

Comment: И какие значения принимает этот счётчик цикла?

Answer (score 3):

в данном случаем можно получить все текстовые содержимые узлов, используя два слеша: `'/td//text()'`

Приведу пример (работает в Python 2.7):

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.fromstring('<td class="name-td alLeft bordR">13.10.2016, Thu<span class="sp">|</span>17:00</td>')
xpathData = tree.xpath('/td//text()')
print ' '.join(xpathData)
```

Выведет:

> 13.10.2016, Thu | 17:00

Comment: не, дело в том, что я не могу вообще получить то, что внутри `td`. этих `td class='bordR'` несколько штук. поэтому я перебираю с помощью цикла `for`. поэтому есть `findall` и  `[count]`. указывая даже принудительно `t.findall(".//td[@class='ck']")[1].text` получаю `list out of index`

Comment: не совесем понятно из вашего примера, выложите пожалуйста весь html код, пример я сделал ответе выше.

Answer (score 2):

я бы рекомендовал вам cssselect

```
PATH = '.name-td'
time = g.cssselect(PATH)[0].text_content()
```

Вывод

> 13.10.2016, Thu|17:00

-

> пример

```
<div class='bla'> 
<table> 
<td> 
<tr>1</tr> 
</td> 
</table> 
</div>
```

c помощью класов у вас было вот так

> PATH = ' .bla table td tr'

а xpath

> ("//div[@class='bla']/table/td/tr")